# Simple Java Program Strange Output

Tags: java

This is my program...

```
import java.lang.Math;
class SquareRoot
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    try
    {
      System.out.println("Enter A Number To Find its Square Root");
      System.out.flush();
      double x = (double) System.in.read();
      double y;
      y = Math.sqrt(x);
      System.out.println("Square Root of " + x + " is " + y);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println("I/O Error! Humein Maaf Kar Do Bhaaya");
    }
  }
}
```

**If I enter 75 as input it shows.. Square Root of  55.0 is <55's square root> 

On entering 23 it shows Square Root of 50.0. Where am I wrong? No problems in compilation.**

I am using DrJava IDE. JDK 7u25 Compiler. Windows 7 32 bit.

Comment: User input is done wrong. Use a `Scanner` instead of `System.in` directly.

Comment: How to do it correctly..? I am new with Java.

Comment: ASCII of 7 (in 75) is 55, while ASCII of 2 (in 23) is 50

Comment: `import java.lang.Math` isn't needed, the `java.lang` package is implicitly imported

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
double x = (double) System.in.read();
```

Nope. I would recommend wrapping this up in a `Scanner`.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
double x = s.nextDouble();
String str = s.nextLine(); // <-- Just an example!
```

Just makes for much nicer code!

**Remember**

Put `import java.util.Scanner` at the top of your page, otherwise Java will kick up a bit of a fuss!

Comment: There is no need to assign `s.nextLine()` to a string if you are using it just to empty the buffer

Comment: I was just using that as an example of it's usage.

Comment: What is String str for?

Comment: Just an example of it's usage. Wow I didn't think it would be this confusing :P

Comment: Gives me this 2 errors found:
File: D:\Projects\Java\SquareRoot\SquareRoot.java  [line: 10]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Scanner
  location: class SquareRoot
File: D:\Projects\Java\SquareRoot\SquareRoot.java  [line: 10]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Scanner
  location: class SquareRoot

Comment: @GunJack did you import `java.util.Scanner`?

Answer (score 8):

`System.in.read()` returns one character. Then its integer representation casted to double.

You may use `BufferedReader`:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s = br.readLine();
double number = Double.parseDouble(s);
```

Or `Scanner`:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
double number = scanner.nextDouble();
```

Comment: Or `Scanner` for simplicity of code and avoid parsing `String` to the data I want/need.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you are casting as a double when getting the user input, it is converting the first character in the input into its ascii value. ('7' = 55, '2' = 50)

Answer (score 1):

Use follows:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
double x = s.nextDouble();
```